# Javascript - lock css rule

Tags: javascript, css, security

Is there any concrete way to lock a css rule on an element to be sure it cannot be altered or changed from the browser?

I put a webkit filter on an element abd i would like this to be not altered or removed but afaik is not possible...?!

Or any way to trigger js to get element css rule to stay also if edited from a person by browser !?

Comment: If by, "from the browser" you mean "by the person using the browser", then no.

Comment: I wonder what kind of security issues you would find with CSS since this is only for styling.

Comment: HTML, Javascript and CSS content are downloaded to the client's computer... Therefore, he will be able to manipulate it as he please. Browsers actually provide nice tools for that. - Nothing that would hurt you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the !important CSS rule to make sure none of your other CSS rules override something, for example:

```
p {
    color: red !important;
}
```

This would ensure all p tags get colored red, and that nothing with a higher priority changes the color to something else.

There is no way to prevent a user from altering HTML, CSS or Javascript from their browser.

Comment: `p { color: blue !important; }` - I just overwrote it. ;-)

Comment: `html body parentX parentY p { color: blue !important; }` is maybe little bit better. It is not so easy to accidentally override if you tell all parent elements. Anyway some later style might override it.

Comment: @Zachary mine would be a security stuff !important can be edited anyway from the browser ;P

Comment: If your concern is security, you shouldn't be relying on CSS to show/hide things. Security should be handled on the server side, and if there's something you don't want the user to see, you shouldn't render it to the page at all.